# Mongoose callback not working using Forever

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, forever

I am trying to run a background process with Forever that adds data from an external service into my mongodb database every hour (I am new with node and had no idea about how to do this). I am using Node with Express and running the forever task using

```
forever -o out.log -e err.log start background/collector.js
```

so I have some feedback from the process. The code is the following:

```
var request = require('request');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Model = require('../models/Model.js');

// Starting the collector process
addNewData();

function addNewData() {
    request('external_service_url', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var models = JSON.parse(body);

            console.log('Adding the new models...')
            for(var i = 0; i < models.length; i++)
            {
                console.log(i);

                Model.create(models[i], function (error, post, result) {
                    console.log('Test');
                    if (error) console.log('Something went wrong adding the document!');
                    if ( ! result.updatedExisting)
                    {
                        console.log('A new document has been added!');
                    }
                });
            }

            console.log('Models added: ' + models.length);

            // Every hour we will collect new data

            console.log('Waiting for an hour...');
            setTimeout(addNewData, 36000000);
        }
    })
}
```

I don't know why but seems that the `.create()` callback is not working, the console.logs placed inside the create callback are not showing anything in the logs. Forever does not work with mongoose? Do you have some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here's the thing. You never "connected" your mongoose adapter to the database. Simply fixed by adding:

```js
mongoose.connect('mongodb://myhost/mydatabase');
```

Somewhere near the top before you attempt to do anything else. It won't necessarily "connect" in that order, but the mongoose methods will work it out. "Asynchronous Programming", read on for the rest.

Also you should not be looping like this since you are not waiting for the "callback" ( it's not a closure it's a callback ) to complete or otherwise "throttle" the connection, which can lead to problems.

Use something like ["async"](https://github.com/caolan/async) instead to handle this. In this example the [`.eachLimit()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) in order to limit the number of parallel operations to a reasonabe level:

```js
async.eachLimit(models,10,function(el,callback) {
    Model.create(models[i], function (error, result) {
        // do something maybe but call
        callback(err);   // to signal it is done
    });
},function(err) {
    // comes here on completion or error
});
```

Remember that "asychronous" code needs to execute on "callbacks" or "promises" in order to signal when things are done. Unline in "scynchronous" programming where each next line only executes when the previous lines of code are complete.

Your "for" loop otherwise just "sends everything" to the server and does not wait for completion before continuing execution.

But the main problem here was the connection. But you still should fix the rest as shown.

Comment: Oh you are right, I was connecting to mongodb in my app.js file, but this script has nothing to do with the app.js file. Seems that now is working. You are right, I meant callbacks sorry, I am always confusing both words! I know that I am not creating the documents synchronously but I don't mind in this case, seems that is working fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @miquelarranz Yes. Connecting in `app.js` or other "main module code" is the standard for long running applications. But of course this "script" is stanalone, so you need to do that there. The other advice here is something that you really need to follow, lest you run into problems in the future.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate the advice :) I am testing know the script and seems that the setTimeout is not working, the script is constantly adding new documents. Maybe its something related to the fact that everything works asynchronously? Any idea?

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it, was using wrongly the eachLimit function. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @miquelarranz If you have more questions then please post new questions here as I sure someone will answer them. I already gave you the advice here that your insertions need to "wait" until completion berfore the rest of your script continues. The only "hint" I will offer here is that this is likely a job for "cron" style processing rather than what you are presently trying to do.